# How to relocate "content and files" from SiteA to SiteB?

Tags: site

can someone show me how can I relocate "content and files" from SiteA to SiteB? I've looked into site setting, but couldn't find the slution. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of options, both using out of the box tools or 3rd party programs.

If you want to use whats out of the box, I find the easiest way is to create list / library templates, download these, and upload them to the new target site. Then you can re-create these lists / libraries with the content intact on the new site.

Here are the steps to do this (Assuming you are going to Site A and moving content to Site B).

1. Navigate to Site A
2. Navigate to the list / library you wish to migrate
3. On the ribbon located at the top, go to list settings or library settings
4. Select the option to save list / library as a template
5. Be sure to check mark "Include Content" if you want the list items / files
6. Save the template, this will be stored in the list gallery of the site.
7. Navigate to the list gallery (can be done through site settings)
8. Download the template you created (this will download a STP file on to your computer)
9. Navigate to Site B
10. Click on Site Settings, than the list gallery
11. Upload the STP file you downloaded in step 8
12. Click on the Gear Icon on the top right, and "Add an App"
13. Select the list / library that you uploaded (this will create list / library that is exactly like the one from Site A)

You can repeat those steps for multiple libraries. There are also 3rd party paid tools like Sharegate that handles migration as well.

I hope that helps.